# how to get the text attribute from the below HTML using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Below is the html code where i want to extract the text "Page 2 of 2" from it

HTML code

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="GridHeader_Sonetto"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_MainCategoriserContent_Map1_SubgroupsAndProducts1_plcCategoryProductsGrid_ctl00_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_SelectSelectCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderContent$MainCategoriserContent$Map1$SubgroupsAndProducts1$plcCategoryProductsGrid$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$SelectSelectCheckBox" onclick="$find(&quot;ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_MainCategoriserContent_Map1_SubgroupsAndProducts1_plcCategoryProductsGrid_ctl00&quot;)._selectAllRows(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderContent$MainCategoriserContent$Map1$SubgroupsAndProducts1$plcCategoryProductsGrid$ctl00$ctl00&quot;, &quot;&quot;, event);setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderContent$MainCategoriserContent$Map1$SubgroupsAndProducts1$plcCategoryProductsGrid$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$SelectSelectCheckBox\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" /></th><th scope="col" class="GridHeader_Sonetto" style="display:none;">_InternalID</th><th scope="col" class="GridHeader_Sonetto" style="display:none;">_ID</th><th scope="col" class="GridHeader_Sonetto" style="display:none;">_Name</th><th scope="col" class="GridHeader_Sonetto" style="display:none;">_Order</th><th scope="col" class="GridHeader_Sonetto" style="display:none;">_Source</th><th scope="col" class="GridHeader_Sonetto" style="display:none;">_RootConcept</th><th scope="col" class="GridHeader_Sonetto">TPNB</th><th scope="col" class="GridHeader_Sonetto">Product Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead><tfoot>
        <tr class="GridPager_Sonetto">
            <td colspan="3"><div class="PagerLeft_Sonetto">
                <span class="items-summary">Items 11 - 15 of 15</span><span class="grid-pages"><span><input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderContent$MainCategoriserContent$Map1$SubgroupsAndProducts1$plcCategoryProductsGrid$ctl00$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl02" value=" " title="Previous Page" class="rgPagePrev" /></span>&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderContent$MainCategoriserContent$Map1$SubgroupsAndProducts1$plcCategoryProductsGrid$ctl00$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl03" value=" " onclick="return false;" title="Next Page" class="rgPageNext" />
            </div><div class="PagerRight_Sonetto">
                </span><span class="hide page-summary">Page 2 of 2</span>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot><tbody>
```

below is my code attempt

```
urll = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_MainCategoriserContent_Map1_SubgroupsAndProducts1_plcCategoryProductsGrid_ctl00_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_SelectSelectCheckBox']")
            urll.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='hide page-summary']").get_attribute("textContent")
```

the above code is working but it is extracting the text of another one before this HTML code
please help on getting the text page 2 of 2!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elem=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='hide page-summary']")

print(elem[2].get_attribute("textContent"))
```

If there are two elements index the second one.

Also when indexing from parent use a .// otherwise you'll get from root.

Comment: im getting the below error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

Comment: Try the updated one. Might have to use 1 if it only finds one. Or just use find_element.

Comment: This worked with a 1 instead of 2
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='hide page-summary']")
print(elem[1].get_attribute("textContent"))

Thank You!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the .text

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('hide page-summary').text
print(element)
```

Comment: when i run the above code i get a No such element exception

Comment: try 'hide.page-summary',  it sometimes works if you don't have any spaces in the class name @ArjunMunirathinam

Comment: try this - driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='hide page-summary']")

Comment: add some time.sleep(3) as well, reason could be that selenium is looking for an element that hasn't finished loading yet @ArjunMunirathinam

Comment: returns a blank space when i run the below
element =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='hide page-summary']").text
print(element)